# Background gradient overflows the text, while it shouldn't

Tags: html, css

Here's the full example with code: http://jsfiddle.net/544jdsnr/

In case the link is invalid:

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="g1">
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="color:#fff;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column">
        <div class="fs30 tupcase tcenter">NO GRADIENT TEXT</div>
        <div class="fs52 tupcase tcenter">PARTIAL GRADIENT</div>
        <div class="fs20 tcenter" style="margin-top:20px">GRADIENT</div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.g1{
    position: absolute;
    top:250px;
    min-width:1000px;
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1);
}
.container{width:1000px;height:100%;margin:0 auto}
.tupcase{text-transform:uppercase}
.tcenter{text-align:center}
.fs52{font-size:52px}
.fs30{font-size:30px}
.fs20{font-size:20px}
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;min-width:1000px;min-height:100%}
header{height:500px;background:#0af}
```

I can't understand why the gradient overflows the text making it darker. Being in another div, it looks like very-very wrong behaviour. Seen in Chrome 42 and Firefox 38.

Comment: Add `z-index:-1;` to the `.g1`.

Comment: @user4875251 the gradient stops working, already tried it

Comment: just to be clear, you want the gradient to still be active, but behind the white text? Correct?

`.g1{z-index:-1;}`
`.fs52{z-index:1;}`  

Works for me on fiddle.

Comment: is this what you try to achieve ? http://jsfiddle.net/544jdsnr/5/  ... no need of an extra container unless you want the gradient over the text ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation for the simple answer of setting a positive z-index on your text div like so:

```
  .fs52 {
    font-size: 52px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

is the display property on your container div.
Since your container div has a display property of "**flex**" the child elements are displayed as "**box**", for elements positioned as box, the z-index property specifies the stack level of the box in the current stacking context. Just like it does for positioned elements with a value of "**absolute**", "**relative**" and "**fixed**"

So the easiest way for you to bring your text layer up front is to set it's z-index. Since all the other elements on your page do not have a z-index set they are rendered on the default rendering layer 0,
they refer to the default stacking order which means for

**descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance**  and

**descendant blocks in the normal flow, in order of appearance**.

And since standard block elements in the normal flow without a position property always render before positioned elements they appear below positioned elements, 
even if they come later in the HTML document.

Which is the reason why your gradient div was on top of all other elements, since it has an absolute position even if there was no z-index set on the gradient div element. So setting the z-index on your text div
will specify a different stacking order. A positive value brings the element up front being rendered on the layer you specify with the value of z-index.

Negative values are also possible to render an element on a layer underneath elements which are on a layer with a greater z-index value or elements which are on the default stacking order on layer 0.

Answer (score 3):

Add `position:relative;z-index:9;` in '.container' class

.container{position:relative;z-index:9;}

http://jsfiddle.net/544jdsnr/4/

Answer (score 2):

I'd add z-index rule to your `.fs` class:

```
.fs52 {
  font-size: 52px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This places your text on top of everything else

Comment: Yes, it works. I'd appreciate if you add some documented explanation on this matter.

Comment: Sure, let me put all of this together

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it could be done with a single container:

```css
.container{
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
 background: -o-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1);
}
.width100{width:100%}
html,body {height:100%;}
.container{width:1000px;height:100%;margin:0 auto}
.tupcase{text-transform:uppercase}
.tcenter{text-align:center}
.fs52{font-size:52px}
.fs30{font-size:30px}
.fs20{font-size:20px}
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;min-width:1000px;min-height:100%}
header{height:500px;background:#0af}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="container" style="color:#fff;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column">
  <div class="fs30 tupcase tcenter">NO GRADIENT TEXT</div>
  <div class="fs52 tupcase tcenter">PARTIAL GRADIENT</div>
  <div class="fs20 tcenter" style="margin-top:20px">GRADIENT</div>
 </div>
</header>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/544jdsnr/5/

Answer (score 0):

As documentation states, `z-index` only works on positioned elements (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`).

To achieve my goal, I have to put `position:relative` in the `.container` class and only then I'd be able to make `z-index` work:

```
.containter {
    ...
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Or I could directly meddle with the `.container` children, like this:

```
.fs52 {
    font-size: 52px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

But this approach is not as nice, for it worsens the code readability.

Comment: I have to disagree here, as all works without setting up `position:relative` on `.container`. Simple `z-index:1` on child element - '.fs52` does the job, which is surprising providing that according to spec z-index should affect only non-static elements, and your `.container` along with its children are **static** by default :)

Comment: @robjez thanx for the input, but I think, putting any properties like that as close to the tree root as possible is vital for code readability. Meaning it's easier to read the code if `z-index` goes to the parent (which is `.container`) than to the children (`.f52`), even if you have to alter the parent with relative positioning.

Comment: Valid point and your solution definitely works, but this case also shows some peculiar behaviour when using `display:flexbox` on element, which surprisingly affects stacking order of its elements. Now the question is why all works by simply stating `z-index:1` on child element. The same doesn't work when changing `display` to ie. `block`. Interesting